# Problem of using FFMPEGIO to write an mp3 file to BytesIO

Tags: python, ffmpeg, bytesio

I wanna download an only-audio video from YouTube and then convert it into mp3 format using ffmpegio and I wanna save everything into buffers so I met the issue.

What should happen: save ffmpeg output to byio (BytesIO)
What happens: console error

```
from pytube import YouTube
from io import BytesIO
import ffmpegio

yt = YouTube("link")
byio = BytesIO()
stream = yt.streams.get_audio_only()
stream.stream_to_buffer(byio)
ffmpegio.transcode(byio.getbuffer(), byio, overwrite=True) # i dont know how to make it write as byio mp3 or something
byio.seek(1)
```

CONSOLE OUTPUT:

```
"stdout": stdout,
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'stdout' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Edit the question to explain what happens, what should happen. If there is an error message, show it as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Is this really the whole error message?

Comment: no. it isnt but i solved my issue just not converting the file and leaving it as it is but renaming the .mp4 to .mp3

Comment: Hey, I'm the ffmpegio dev. `transcode` is not the right function for your purpose. What's the content of `byio.getbuffer()`?

Comment: If you want to give it another look, feel free to drop in on the [GitHub Disccussions board](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpegio/discussions)